# how can I use an external GPIO sound card and set it as default?

Tags: gpio, audio

I've bought a seeed voice card as an external GPIO sound card and as a input audio device to use pocket sphinx.After it was installed successfully, i typed "cat /proc/asound/cards" to see my card index and it displayed:

```
0 [ALSA           ]: bcm2835_alsa - bcm2835 ALSA
                     bcm2835 ALSA
1 [seeed2micvoicec]: seeed-2mic-voic - seeed-2mic-voicecard
                     seeed-2mic-voicecard
```

then i typed"cat /proc/asound/modules" and i found something that i'm not so sure whether right or not:

```
0 snd_bcm2835
1 snd_soc_simple_card
```

My question is, how can I use the device which index is 1, or should I say, how I off the bcm2835 and make seeed2micvoicec into the index "0"? And does it supposed to be 1 snd_soc_seeed_2mic_voic in /proc/asound/modules, why it is snd_soc_simple_card?

Comment: don’t load the driver for onboard audio. /boot/config.txt

Comment: did you mean that i had to make: Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=off  in /boot/config.txt ,i already did this, but it's still not working, i think it should not be the snd_soc_simple_card because i don't think it's my own voice card's driver, but i can't modify this, did you know why and how?thanks!

Comment: unload the kernel module. ftp://ftp.belnet.be/mirrors/www.tldp.org/en/Module-HOWTO/x197.html